# KDE saves and restores all but Google Chrome in its Desktop saved session

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde, session

For some reason when enabling `Restore manually saved session` in `Desktop Session Login and Logout` settings, and hitting `Save Session` from the applications menu - all opened application windows get saved and restored upon login into the KDE session, except `google chrome`.

I located the session file `~/.config/ksmserverrc` and indeed firefox and many other applications are there:

```
$ grep firefox ~/.config/ksmserverrc
program11=firefox
restartCommand11=/usr/bin/firefox,--sm-client-id,10686f70[...]
$ grep gkrellm ~/.config/ksmserverrc
program12=/usr/bin/gkrellm
restartCommand12=/usr/bin/gkrellm,--sm-client-id,10686f70[...]
$ grep chrome ~/.config/ksmserverrc
```

as you can see chrome is not there.

And no application has been configured to be excluded:

```
$ grep excludeApps ~/.config/ksmserverrc
excludeApps=
```

The only unusual thing about chrome, as compared to other applications, perhaps, is that it appears as many threads in the output of `ps(1)`.

I have it installed as:

```
$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
google-chrome-stable is already the newest version (69.0.3497.100-1)
```

My setup: Kubuntu 18.04, Plasma 5.12.6, KDE Frameworks 5.44

Comment: I see what you see. Also, when I opened Google Chrome manually, there was a message about it not being shutdown properly. Maybe you could file a bug report if you have a Launchpad account.

Comment: I can create an account. Would [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdebase-workspace/) be the right place to report this issue in, @DKBose?

Comment: See https://wiki.kubuntu.org/Kubuntu/Bugs/Reporting

Comment: Thanks. What I needed help with is to find which package it should be reported for, which the wiki wasn't helpful for - googling I found the right package. Bug report [submitted](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-workspace/+bug/1793242).

Comment: Confirmed your bug. Let's see what happens!